# Python 3 import anomaly

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-import

Consider the following directory structure,

```
parent
├── __init__.py
├── mod1.py
├── mod2.py
└── mod3.py
```

Contents of the files and python version are,

```
$ cat __init__.py 
from . import mod1
hello = "parent Hello"

$ cat mod1.py
from . import mod2
hello = "parent.mod1 Hello"

$ cat mod2.py
hello = "parent.mod2 hello"

$ cat mod3.py
hello = "parent.mod3 Hello"

$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Now in an interactive session I get the following behavior,

```
>>> import parent
>>> parent.mod1
<module 'parent.mod1' from '/home/codeman/mydata/local/tmp/parent/mod1.py'>
>>> parent.mod2
<module 'parent.mod2' from '/home/codeman/mydata/local/tmp/parent/mod2.py'>
>>> parent.mod3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'parent' has no attribute 'mod3'
```

Why is `parent.mod2` accessible when I had only imported `mod1` in the `parent/__int__.py` file ? (is it a bug?)

I understand that AttributeError with `parent.mod3` occurs because only the modules imported in the `__init__.py` file are accessible when plainly importing the parent using `import parent` syntax.

Comment: `mod2` is accessible, because you imported it in `mod1`

Comment: @vaultah shouldn't is be visible only inside `parent.mod1`? I haven't imported it in the `__init__.py`.

Comment: The short answer is: it doesn't matter where you import it. The `mod2` attribute is added to the "shared" `parent` module object. If you have the `parent` object, you can access the `mod2` attribute everywhere.

Comment: @vaultah that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you import a module, Python creates a module object and stores it in the [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) dictionary. Subsequent imports of that same module will reuse the module object from `sys.modules`. Additionally, each time you import a *sub*module, the attribute is added to the parent module object.

There's one instance of `sys.modules` for a given Python process, and therefore *in general* there's only one instance of every module per Python process. It means that if you have access to a module object, you also have access to its submodules that have been imported anywhere within the current process.

In this particular case, `import package` runs *package/__init__.py*, which imports `package.mod1`, which imports `package.mod2`. As a result, `mod1` and `mod2` are added to the "shared" `parent` module object, and you can access them.

Comment: The last line of second para sums up the whole thing. Thanks! After the stmt `from x.y import z`, I see x and y being imported too in sys.modules. Can their import be avoided (for speedup) if z is a submodule/package which doesn't require the processing of `__init__.py` of parent modules?

Comment: @codeman48 each `__init__.py` should only be ran once, so unless they need a lot of resources (and they should not), I wouldn't worry about it. Anyway, I am not aware of a clean way to do that. If `z` is only peripheral to `x`/`y`, I would consider splitting `x` (or its submodules) into [namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) (these are defined without `__init__.py` files).